# Google Play library 3.0 check if user used introductory price

Tags: android, in-app-billing, android-billing, play-billing-library

I am using Google Play Billing library 3.0.3 with Java.
I have an introductory price on my subscriptions.

When the user already have used the introductory price, the getIntroductoryPrice() function from Google billing library still returns the introductory price.

How can I check if the user already used the introductory price for not showing it again to the user?

I want to show the introductory price just the first time, when the user have not yet used it.

Comment: have you found the answer?

Comment: No, I did not find the answer